# Regular expression to eliminate double period (..) for file upload

Tags: regex

I want to avoid .. for image files.  In my validations, the regex reads:

```
%r{\.(gif|png|jpg)$}i
```

for image URLs.  The problem is that fred..png will also pass instead of recognising the double ..

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Which language is this? Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent the case you described, which would only be for a double dot right before the extension:

```
%r{[^.]\.(gif|png|jpg)$}i
```

Edit: If you want to have it such that `..` is *nowhere* in the string, it would be easiest to do that in code (pseudo: `if regex.matches(filename) and '..' not in filename`).

Comment: Have you tried this? Doesn't work. Because it sees the `.` and stops. That is why you have to use look behinds.

Comment: My bad, was considering empty names.

Comment: I guess it's up to the OP if he wants "..gif" to be valid or not. Doesn't sound like it, though.

Answer (score 2):

Something like below maybe?

```
%r{\.(?<!\.\.)(gif|png|jpg)$}i
```

Doing a negative lookbehind to see `..` doesn't occur